# Making efficient code using re.findall to sort files in folder

Tags: python, findall

This is how the files are named in the folder :

```
Data20210608_FL_.xlsx
Data20210608_FLFR_.xlsx
Data20210510-fl_.xlsx
Data20210510-flfr_.xlsx
Data20210608_LRC_.xlsx
Data20210609_LRC_.xlsx
```

I would like to:

1. use a loop to open only the ones containing FL or FLFR
2. separate between the ones ending with FL and the ones ending with FLFR;

This is my code but it does not work and I don't fully understand how to use re.findall

```
 import glob
 import os
 import re
 import pandas as pd

 # %%
 directory = r'C:/ .../Licor/'
 appendix = "_.xlsx"
 location = directory + appendix

 datafinal = pd.DataFrame()

 #%%
 for filepath in glob.iglob(location):
     print(filepath)

     head_tail = os.path.split(filepath)

     Treatment = re.findall("[_FL][^_]*", head_tail[1])[0] 
     data = pd.read_excel(filepath)

     data['Spectrum']= Treatment
     datafinal= pd.concat([datafinal, data])
```

Thank you!

Comment: When matching filenames, is letter case significant?

Comment: you could simply check `if "FLFR_" in filename:`. And if you want to open also `flfr_` then you could use `upper()` like `if "FLFR_" in filename.upper():`

Comment: as for me your main problem is that you don't use `if` to check if you found file with `FL`

Comment: `does not work` is the most useless infromation. If you get error message then show FULL error message in question (not in comment) as text (not image). We can't run your code, we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it by too complicated way, try:

```py
import os

for fn in os.listdir("./"):
    fn_without_ext = os.path.splitext(fn)[0]
    if fn_without_ext.endswith("FLFR_"):
        print(fn)  # do your FLFR stuff
    if fn_without_ext.endswith("FL_"):
        print(fn)  # do your FL stuff
```

More info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: `FL_` and `FLFR_` are not extensions but part of name. They are always in the same place in text then you could get `fn[13:]`. You could also convert to `upper()` because there is also `fl_`, `flfr_`. You could put example filenames as one `text` and use `text.split("\n")` instead of `os.listdir()` to test it.